# Asynchronous in cURL Which has a foreach loop

Tags: php, asynchronous, curl

I have a web service that returns a result for each of my $maparams. I don't want my ring to wait until it gets the result and then goes to the next $maparams and the program doesn't run linearly. Is that possible?

```
$maparams = ['a1','a2', 'a3', 'a4'];
foreach ($maparams as $maparam) {
    $arr = [
        "api_token" => "VSwpSOcLlanVwnX0C7rqRBKy3b",
        "tset" => [[
            'param' => $maparam,
            'source' => "UGTT",
            'end' => "TTQH",
       
        ]],
    ];

    $url = 'http://mywebservice.com/api';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $payload = json_encode($arr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_decode($result, true);
}
```

Comment: Check out multi_curl ...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz i check this , I found examples to request multiple addresses but I couldn't find anything for the post value, can you bring an example or sample for my code?

Comment: Huh? where's the problem exactly? configure each curl handle like before...